# Android Beam only in a dialog

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

The app I am working on has just one activity with 5 tabs in a ViewPager.
I want to call a dialog on two devices. Only when this dialog is open the app should be allowed to accept Android Beam messages.

I don't want the user to use Android Beam without the dialog open.
Is there a way to block Android Beam?

I only found solutions to block Android Beam in activities. But I only have one activity.

Comment: just create a new activity and use a `Dialog` theme. It will look like a dialog, but it will be a whole activity. Something like `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` should work..

Comment: this is not possible in my app. the app loads hundrets of views at start. this takes several seconds. and also it communicates with the server at different times. i would need to start this main activity again after the nfc-transaction right? this is really time intensive

Comment: but this is not the question here ^^